# File Upload doesn't read the file being uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

Im trying to upload an excel file using the file upload but whenever I do "If (FileUpload.HasFile)" it always return false even I already selected a file. Below is my code when I click the upload button.

(EDITED: The if statement finally becomes true when I upload a file another problem is this error message show "The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/Datas/Book1.xlsx' is not rooted."
)

> Blockquote

```
  protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs("~/Datas/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
            Label1.Text = "File name: " +
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                "Content type: " +
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
            string FileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
            string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/Datas/" + FileUpload1.FileName));

            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);

            OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", OleDbcon);
            OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //Dt.Clear(); ds.Clear();
            objAdapter1.Fill(ds);
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Dt = ds.Tables[0];
            DataColumn dc = Dt.Columns.Add("Ser", typeof(Int32));
            int count = 0;
            foreach (DataRow item in Dt.Rows)
            {
                count++;
                item["Ser"] = count;
            }

            TraineeGrid.DataSource = Dt;
            TraineeGrid.DataBind();
        }
             catch (Exception ex)
           {
                 Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
           }
       }

        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
        }
    }
```

> I have this table that consists of buttons and this is where the file upload and upload button located

```
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btnStyle" ID="enableFilter" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="100px" OnClick="filterMode_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btnStyle" ID="newTraineeBtn" runat="server" Text="Add" width="100px" OnClick="newTraineeBtn_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btnStyle" ID="enableDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" width="100px" OnClientClick ="if (!confirm ('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')) return false;" OnClick="enableDelete_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btnStyle" ID="enableEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" Width="100px" OnClick="enableEdit_Click" />     
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btnStyle" ID="showColList"  runat="server" Text="Columns" OnClientClick="javascript:openPopup('ColumnList.aspx', 'xtf', '500', '405')" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    //file upload happens here 
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload" />

             // I tried to add this code because they said it might work but it actually doesn't
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
                    </Triggers>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: can you show your html? are you using update panel?

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools and show us the payload being posted to the endpoint.

Comment: you have a blank exception block...you should never have a blank exception block...thus tells you went wrong

Comment: Im just a beginner so I dont know most of the tools that youre saying but I have attached my html code above so it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some security reason, FileUpload control will not keep the value during postback.

One way is to set the triggers for your Upload button

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
      <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload"  />
      </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (fileUpload1.HasFile)
        {                
            fileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\" + fileupload1.FileName);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Now there's a server error that says "An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below."

Comment: "The control with ID 'testPanel' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it."

Comment: "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page." It still cant load the page

Comment: Ok so  I deleted the other Scriptmanager and now it accepts the file but I still get this error "ERROR: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/Datas/Book1.xlsx' is not rooted.
" I have also updated the my code above

Comment: @JMVillaflores finally, you resolve your problem?. Don't forget to mark the answer if my answer solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, the html code actually works but I have to do some changes on my cs codes to make it function properly. Anyway, thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried from my end and i am able to get the file.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnok" runat="server" Text="Ok"  OnClick="btnok_Click"/>
```

below event is for the button click.May i know on which place you are getting issue.

```
 protected void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
      {
        var val=FileUpload1.PostedFile;
      }
   }
```

Comment: it still false when i put a linebreak on the if statement